# Crystal printing blank page at the end of the report when subreport is blank

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have what is (hopefully) and quick and simple question.  I have a report that has two subreports in it.  The second of the two subreports, when there is data, needs to be on a new page which is what's causing my problem.  When I add conditions in the formula for New Page Before or New Page After such as: 'Not onlastrecord', conditional formulas in the suppress fields of the main report sections containing the subreports and it just wont work the way I need it.  The subreports are checked "Suppress Printing if No Records" and are as small as they can be to prevent a field spillover problem.  The problem that I have is that I can either get the report to suppress the blank section but when the report has data it is not on a new page, or I can get it on a new page but I get a blank page at the end of the report with only a page header and footer on it (no blank or unsuppressed sections either).  I have combed through several forums and tried several different solutions and combinations of solutions and nothing works.  Anyone that can help me solve this would be my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to split the pages in the main report.

Instead, conditionally set the New Page Before option in the Report Header section of the second subreport, so that it is only true if at least one record is returned - for example, using a condition like `Count ({Table.Field})>0` .

You may need to split the subreport's Report Header section into two subsections, in order to be able to set the New Page Before option - if so, suppress the first subsection and conditionally set the New Page Before option in the second subsection.

Comment: Hey Mark, I tried that but it didnt work the way I'd hoped.  I didnt work in the header with text regardless of which subsection it was in.  When I suppressed the other section the new page command wouldnt work.  Now instead of a blank page at the end I have a blank page before the last section is displayed.  I dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: @EdwardLane: Can you rephrase your comment? I can't understand what you have written.

Comment: sure, sorry.. Per your instructions I had to split my report header into sections to make the New Page Before option available.  I tried adding the conditional statement for the New Page section in the top (blank) subsection of the report header which is above my header text and then suppress that section.  When suppressed the New Page before condition wouldnt work, so I moved the conditional statement to the subsection with my header text which works but only if the subsection above is visible (not suppressed) so now I get a blank page between the main report and the subreport.

Comment: @EdwardLane: Firstly, are you doing this in the **second subreport**? Secondly, you should have **split the subreport's Report Header section into two subsections**, then suppressed the **first** Report Header subsection (Report Header a) and conditionally set the New Page Before option in the **second** Report Header subsection (Report Header b) - *all in the second subreport*.

Comment: I am doing it in the second subreport and I did separate the Report Header into two subsections but when I set the condition in Report Header a, and then suppress it, it does not work properly.  The condition is ignored completely.  It wont work in Report Header b either when Report Header a is suppressed.  Is there a setting in crystal that prevents conditional parameters to be executed when the section is suppressed?

Comment: @EdwardLane: It should work in Report Header b when Report Header a is suppressed. Alternatively, try unsuppressing Report Header a, but shrink it to the smallest size possible, and conditionally set the New Page Before option in Report Header b.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found it was a graphic too far to the right that was falling onto another page.  I found it by printing the report to a PDF using the Acrobat print driver and then opening it up in Acrobat or Reader or Adobe Illustrator.  I then did a select-all on the blank page it showed me a small white box on the page where the graphic from the first page was falling over.  I moved the box back a few millimeters and the blank page disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try check the option 'Suppress Blank Section'